# проблема с трансформацие scale

Tags: html, css

хочу сделать так чтобы трансформированное изображение не выходило за рамки блока, а "обрезалось" когда изображение превышает размер блока.(изображение перекрывает бордер блока)

[код](https://jsfiddle.net/ovtd9x7b/3/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="block">
    <img src="https://assets.imgix.net/logos/customer-homepage-logos-May-2019.ai?page=10&fm=png8&bg=ffffff" alt="">
  </div>
</body>
</html>

/* css */

    body{
  background: purple;
}
.block{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  z-index: 10;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .4s;
  z-index: 5;
}
img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  transition: .8s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все что нужно это добавить св-во `overflow: hidden`, оно не позволяет дочерним компонентам выходить за рамки элемента ( но есть и исключения )

Подробнее: http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow

```css
body{
  background: purple;
}

.block{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden; // достаточно добавить это св-во
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .4s;
  z-index: 5;
}

img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.4,1.4);
  transition: .8s;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://assets.imgix.net/logos/customer-homepage-logos-May-2019.ai?page=10&fm=png8&bg=ffffff" alt="">
</div>
```